# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) code=2 on genymotion emulator not using NDK

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-ndk, libc, genymotion

My application does not use NDK. I am testing it on the GenyMotion Nexus 7 emulator and the problem is quite hard to reproduce and I still haven't figured out a correct way to reproduce it. Sometimes the application works fine for a long time and sometimes it just crashes and automatically restarts after about 30 seconds of using.

**EDIT: I am not 100% but it only happens on genymotion emulator, but not regular android emulator (I will continue testing).**

The problem started happenning when I added support for a large screen when in landscape mode (started displaying two fragments at once in landscape and only 1 in portrait (with width smaller than 720)).

One of the fragments lazy loads images (from memory, disk or internet).

I am quite new to this dynamic adding and removing of fragments so I'm sure there could be something there.

Anyway please help me decode this dump and figure out what's causing the crash (I will try to ommit stuff I think isn't important):

```
12-17 16:52:18.344    1255-1255/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x97858094 (code=2), thread 1255 (hiexpressgradle)
12-17 16:52:18.448      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-17 16:52:18.448      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86tp/vbox86tp:4.3/JLS36G/eng.buildbot.20131127.101043:userdebug/test-keys'
12-17 16:52:18.448      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '0'
12-17 16:52:18.448      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 1255, tid: 1255, name: hiexpressgradle  >>> XXX <<<
12-17 16:52:18.448      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 97858094
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ eax 00000000  ebx b754a6fc  ecx 0000000e  edx 978580a2
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ esi 0000000c  edi 00000001
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ eip b754a6fc  ebp b94985e8  esp bfe29398  flags 00210292
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? E/Corkscrew﹕ unrecognized DW_CFA_* instruction: 0x10
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 0002f6fc  /system/lib/libc.so (memset+140)
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  pc 00015c6f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::FontRenderer::cacheBitmap(SkGlyph const&, android::uirenderer::CachedGlyphInfo*, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, bool)+511)
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  pc 00011aea  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::Font::precache(SkPaint*, char const*, int)+922)
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03  pc 0001414e  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::FontRenderer::precache(SkPaint*, char const*, int, android::uirenderer::Matrix4 const&)+78)
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04  pc 00024aa6  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::DrawTextOp::onDefer(android::uirenderer::OpenGLRenderer&, int*, void**)+486)
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29358  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe2935c  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29360  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29364  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29368  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe2936c  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29370  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29374  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29378  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe2937c  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29380  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29384  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29388  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe2938c  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29390  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29394  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  bfe29398  b5ba5aac  /system/lib/libhwui.so
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe2939c  b5b3ec70  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::FontRenderer::cacheBitmap(SkGlyph const&, android::uirenderer::CachedGlyphInfo*, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, bool)+512)
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  bfe293a0  97858094
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293a4  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293a8  0000000e
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293ac  bfe2940c  [stack]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293b0  b9726ae4  [heap]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293b4  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293b8  b934c340  [heap]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293bc  b6bff210  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkGlyphCache::findImage(SkGlyph const&)+144)
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293c0  b972f550  [heap]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293c4  b934b588  [heap]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293c8  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293cc  00000032
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293d0  bfe29410  [stack]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293d4  bfe2940c  [stack]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293d8  97858008
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe293dc  b6eb8d48  /system/lib/libskia.so
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ ........  ........
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  bfe29430  b94985e8  [heap]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29434  b9726ae4  [heap]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29438  b966b9c8  [heap]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe2943c  bfe29470  [stack]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29440  bfe29474  [stack]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29444  00000001
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29448  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe2944c  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29450  3f800000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29454  00000010
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29458  b966b9c8  [heap]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe2945c  b9670dc6  [heap]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29460  b94907a4  [heap]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29464  b9670e28  [heap]
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe29468  3f800026
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ bfe2946c  00000000
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ ........  ........
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory map around fault addr 97858094:
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ 977fa000-97858000 r-x /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ 97858000-97859000 r-x
12-17 16:52:18.608      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ 97859000-978d9000 rw-
```

Thanks for your input @Simon, after some testing I started to get an error on the android emulator aswell. But on the android emulator it was a good old OutOfMemory exception. So it turns out that my drawable manager (on one of the fragments) had a huge memory leak where it would bloat a HashMap with drawables. It only became an issue when I implemented the two pane layout, since the DrawableManager would always stay in memory (because the category selection fragment that holds the manager never gets recreated) even when I switched categories.

**EDIT: Even though I've solved my memory leak, my genymotion emulator still crashes with the same SIGSEGV, So I guess this question is still open.**

Comment: Genymption is not an Android emulator and is not a valid target for testing.  It is a hacked together virtual machine with who knows what changes and hacks in Android to get it you fly.  I would ignore this and move on.

Comment: Hi I am having the same issue can up please look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54760308/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-code-2-fault-addr-0x7fa4c3813c-in-tid-21198-crashly

Answer (score 14):

Tested Solution its work:

mention these permission in manifiest:

```
 <application        
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
        android:allowBackup="true"           
        android:vmSafeMode="true"       
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
```

Comment: Can you leave this when shipping the app as well, or is this only during development?

Comment: `android:debuggable="true"` gives error if using Android Studio, but not needed in my case, not needed either `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

Comment: @CarloRodríguez That time I was using in Eclipse but in android You can remove these permission according to your need

Answer (score 11):

I was experiencing this problem also, Specifically with a 4.3 image on GenyMotion. I switched to a 4.2.2 image and no longer experienced the crash.

Comment: I also switched to 4.2.2 and had no SIGSEGV ever since.

Comment: Same thing here. Switched from 4.3 image to any other image and it worked.

Comment: Similar here too, on 4.3 X86 image of Genymotion.
`android:vmSafeMode="true"` and 
`android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

the solution i found by  myself it's to change some attribute on your androidmanifest.xml file

```
Debuggable = True
VM safe mode =True
Allow Backup = True
Allow Clear user date= True
Hardware Accelerated = True
```

(i did this and i dont have this problem and my application ran without problem and i m using Genymotion Too )
On Application menu sorry i forgot this

Comment: when u open your androidmanifest.xml you see menus at the bottom (manifest, application,permissions,instrumentations,androidmanifest.xml

Comment: @VM tell if it works i have edited my first answer and i think it will  work

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I've just moved on from this issue.