# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x7fa4c3813c in tid 21198 (Crashlytics Exc)

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, runtime-error

I am developing an app and everything worked fine until now. I get errors like this one:

```
libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x7fa4c3813c in tid 21198 (Crashlytics Exc)
```

and it makes my app crash. I use a real device (Xiomi note 4 pro) to test my app.
I am really lost, so if someone has any idea even on how to get more info about the errors, **please help**

**Stack track:-**

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2019-02-19 11:42:30.014 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/santoni/santoni:7.1.2/N2G47H/V10.1.1.0.NAMMIFI:user/release-keys'
2019-02-19 11:42:30.014 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2019-02-19 11:42:30.014 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2019-02-19 11:42:30.015 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG: pid: 21159, tid: 21198, name: Crashlytics Exc  >>> com.test.myapp <<<
2019-02-19 11:42:30.015 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7fa4c3813c
2019-02-19 11:42:30.015 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000007fa4c38040  x1   0000000000000000  x2   0000000000000041  x3   000000000000000e
2019-02-19 11:42:30.015 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000000  x6   8000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
2019-02-19 11:42:30.015 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000007fb0d7adf8  x9   00000000000297a0  x10  0000000000000001  x11  0000000000000000
2019-02-19 11:42:30.015 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG:     x12  000000000000003e  x13  00000000000007c0  x14  000000000000000c  x15  2e8ba2e8ba2e8ba3
2019-02-19 11:42:30.015 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007fb0d836e8  x17  0000007fb0ca65a4  x18  0000007fae788038  x19  0000007fa4c3813c
2019-02-19 11:42:30.015 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000007fa4c38000  x21  0000007fa44624c0  x22  0000000012e7bd60  x23  0000000000000000
2019-02-19 11:42:30.015 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000007fa44624c0  x25  a89df4d580570a0f  x26  0000007fa0ac1a98  x27  a89df4d580570a0f
2019-02-19 11:42:30.015 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000000000000002  x29  0000007f92088170  x30  0000007fb0cb28f4
2019-02-19 11:42:30.015 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f92088150  pc   0000007fb0ca65d8  pstate 0000000020000000
2019-02-19 11:42:30.019 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2019-02-19 11:42:30.019 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000000001675d8  /system/lib64/libicui18n.so (_ZN6icu_5612RegexMatcherC2EPKNS_12RegexPatternE+52)
2019-02-19 11:42:30.019 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00000000001738f0  /system/lib64/libicui18n.so (_ZNK6icu_5612RegexPattern7matcherER10UErrorCode+88)
2019-02-19 11:42:30.019 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000001d804  /system/lib64/libjavacore.so
2019-02-19 11:42:30.020 21232-21232/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000000074db2d74  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x2f8d000)
```

Comment: try to set `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in android manifest file in application tag

Comment: @RutvikBhatt thanks for the reply but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for me, the problem was parsing Google's Location object with Gson. I created my own SimpleLocation object and it solved the problem. Google's Location object was throwing random Signal 11 error and crashing randomly.

Here is a link to similar problem with better explanation https://github.com/e-mission/e-mission-data-collection/issues/49